# how to put pretty JSON into REST api

Tags: json, web-services, rest, grails

I am trying to build a REST service which accepts `XML` and convert it into `JSON` and call external Service which accepts `JSON` and put my `JSON` into it. I am able to put the json without pretty but I want to PUT the json in pretty format. Please suggest how to do, below is my code ...

```
package com.mypackge

import grails.converters.JSON
import grails.rest.RestfulController
import grails.plugins.rest.client.RestBuilder

class RestCustomerController extends RestfulController {
/*
    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']
    RestCustomerController() {
    super(Customer)
    }
*/
    def index() {
        convertXmlToJson()
    }

    def myJson = ''

    def convertXmlToJson() {
    def xml = ''' <Customer>
            <customerid>9999999999999</customerid>
            <ssn>8888</ssn>
            <taxid>8888</taxid>
            <address>
                            <addressline1>Yamber Ln</addressline1>
                            <addressline1>8664 SE</addressline1>
                            <city>CCCCC</city>
                            <state>CC</state>
                            <zipcode>97679</zipcode>
            </address>
            <firstname>Scott</firstname>
            <middlename></middlename>
            <lastname>David</lastname>
            <account>
                                            <accountno>576-294738943</accountno>
                                            <accounttype>Lease</accounttype>
                                            <accountsubtype></accountsubtype>
                                            <accountstatus>complete</accountstatus>
                                            <firstname>Scott</firstname>
                                            <middlename></middlename>
                                            <lastname>David</lastname>
                                            <businessname></businessname>
                                            <billingsystem>yoiuhn</billingsystem>
                                            <brand></brand>
                                            <plantype></plantype>
                                            <billingaddress>
                                                            <addressline1>Yamber Ln</addressline1>
                                                            <addressline1>8664 SE </addressline1>
                                                            <city>CCCCC</city>
                                                            <state>CC</state>
                                                            <zipcode>97679</zipcode>
                                            </billingaddress>
                                            <job>
                                                            <jobid>8276437463728</jobid>
                                                            <jobstatus>SUCCESS</jobstatus>
                                            </job>
            </account>
            </Customer>
            '''.stripMargin()

        // Parse it
            def parsed = new XmlParser().parseText( xml )

            def myId = parsed.customerid.text()
            // Deal with each node:
            def handle
            handle = { node ->
                if( node instanceof String ) {
                node
                }
                else {
                    [ (node.name()): node.collect( handle ) ]
                }
            }
            // Convert it to a Map containing a List of Maps
            def jsonObject = [ (parsed.name()): parsed.collect { node ->
                            [ (node.name()): node.collect( handle ) ]
                            } ]
            def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(jsonObject) //.toPrettyString()
            // Check it's what we expected
            def mmyresp
                try{
                    mmyresp = putRequest(myId,json)
                }catch(Exception e) {
                    mmyresp = 'Please Validate JSON ....'
                }
    }

    def putRequest(String id, JSON myJson) {
            String url = "http://foo.com/customer/external/"+id
            def rest = new RestBuilder()
            def resp = rest.put(url){
                contentType "application/json"
                json{
                myJson
                }
            }
            return resp
    }

}
```

The record is added in below format ...

```
{"Customer":[{"customerid":["9999999999999"]},{"ssn":["8888"]},
{"taxid":["8888"]},{"address":[{"addressline1":["Yamber Ln"]},
{"addressline1":["8664 SE"]},{"city":["CCCCC"]},{"state":["CC"]},{"zipcode":["97679"]}]},
{"firstname":["Scott"]},{"middlename":[]},{"lastname":["David"]},{"businessname":[]},
{"account":[{"accountno":["576-294738943"]},{"accounttype":["Lease"]},{"accountsubtype":[]},
{"accountstatus":["complete"]},{"firstname":["Scott"]},{"middlename":[]},{"lastname":["David"]},
{"businessname":[]},{"billingsystem":["yoiuhn"]},{"brand":[]},{"plantype":[]},
{"billingaddress":[{"addressline1":["Yamber Ln"]},{"addressline1":["8664 SE"]},
{"city":["CCCCC"]},{"state":["CC"]},{"zipcode":["97679"]}]},{"job":[{"jobid":["8276437463728"]},
,{"jobstatus":["SUCCESS"]}]}]}]}
```

But I want this to be inserted in pretty format. I tried `.toPrettyString()` but got casting exception when try to put as json. I am trying the REST services for the first time, not sure where I am doing wrong. Please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 5):

You should set following field in you `Config.groovy`.

> grails.converters.default.pretty.print = true

This will pretty print for both the xml and json.

you could optionally set it up for xml or json only like below:

**For json**:

> grails.converters.json.pretty.print = true

**For xml**

> grails.converters.xml.pretty.print = true

A sample of `Config.groovy` entry is:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.converters.json.pretty.print = true 
    }
 }
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

For Grails 4, try this:

```
def json = x as JSON
json.prettyPrint = true;
log.info(json.toString())
```